# How can I access the image from the MSMessage's layout on the receiving user's end?

Tags: ios10, imessage, msmessage, msmessagetemplatelayout

I am making an iMessage Extension that involves users sending pictures back and forth to one another. They need to both be able to access the images that they receive from each other and use it on their own end. For example, if USER 1 sends a picture of a puppy to USER 2, the image property of the messages layout would be of the puppy. USER 2 should then be able to tap that message, and the puppy load into an image view on screen. So far I don't know how I would do this.

Here's where I set the layout image to that of a puppy.

```
@IBAction func sendPicturePressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if chosenImage.image != nil {

        let session = MSSession()
        let message = MSMessage(session: session)
        let conversation = self.activeConversation
        let components = URLComponents()

        let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()

        let image = chosenImage.image
        layout.image = image

        message.layout = layout
        message.url = components.url!

        conversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: { (error) in

            self.dismiss()

        })

    }
}
```

Now when the second user taps the puppy, I want to set an image view on their screen to the puppy. Not exactly sure how, but what I'd LIKE to do is:

```
override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {

    imageView.image = conversation.selectedMessage.layout.image

    //There is no image property to access this like I've provided, that's just what I'm trying to accomplish.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't access the layout image that send from another user.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/53174

> The selected Message having a nil layout is expected.  Received
>   messages won't have a layout object filled in.

What you can, is on the sender side, you not only insert a `MSMessage` with image layout to `MSConversation`, but also upload an image copy to your server and mark the web image URL in `MSMessage.URL`.

So next time when user select a message, you can unwrap `MSMessage.URL` and find the image URL, then download it from your server.

Answer (score 2):

Although you cannot access the layout once message *is received*, you still have once chance to get it. In case extension is launched, message's layout is accessible *on arrival* in `-[didReceiveMessage:conversation:]` method of your `MSMessagesAppViewController`-based class.

On the sender side you can assign your message a URL with custom ID (e.g. UUID) - it will be always accessible – then extract it on the receiver side in the `didReceiveMessage` together with the image and cache the latter locally with the ID as a name. Here's the code draft:

```
- (NSURL*) fileURLFromRawURL:(NSURL*)idURL
{
    NSString *fileID = idURL.relativePath;
    NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileID];

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
}

- (MSMessage*) composeMessageWithImage:(UIImage*)image session:(MSSession*)session
{    
    MSMessageTemplateLayout *layout = [MSMessageTemplateLayout new];
    layout.image = image;

    MSMessage *message = [[MSMessage alloc] initWithSession:session];
    message.layout = layout;
    message.URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];

    return message;
}

- (void) didReceiveMessage:(MSMessage *)message conversation:(MSConversation *)conversation 
{
    // Assuming that the extension is launched:
    MSMessageTemplateLayout *layout = message.layout;
    UIImage *img = layout.image;  // you've got the image
    NSURL *path = [self fileURLFromRawURL:message.URL];
    if (path && image){
        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation((UIImage*)resource, 0.8);
        [data writeToURL:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil];
    }
}
```

After that, once message is tapped, the `-[didSelectMessage:conversation:]` will be called. Here you can get the URL again and read the corresponding image from cache (in case it is available):

```
- (void) didSelectMessage:(MSMessage *)message conversation:(MSConversation *)conversation
{ 
    NSURL *path = [self fileURLFromRawURL:message.URL];
    if (path){
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:path];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add all necessary checks for `nil`s, successfull URL creation etc.

Comment: This is great!  In fact, the file is already accessible in layout.mediaFileURL, so just need to copy.  Is this documented anywhere?  message.layout is an MSMessageLayout object with no accessible members, so that is a little worrisome that it must be cast to MSMessageTemplateLayout.

Comment: Ahh, but just realized, as you said, it only works for messages that arrive while the extension is active.  Bummer.  Not sure why Apple makes this data unavailable.

Comment: Because there needs to be a context around the data that was created by your extension; otherwise, you could access any image from any message in the transcript, regardless of whether it originated from your extension.